# Errors when attempting to train on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using [this](https://github.com/pender/chatbot-rnn/blob/master/train.py) and trying to train it on my GPU rather than CPU.
When I use 
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation cost: Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]

  [[node cost (defined at D:\Documents\CHATBOT\chatbot-rnn\model.py:222)  = ScalarSummary[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/device:GPU:0"](cost/tags, Mean)]]
```

That's really it. I have a working installation of tf-gpu and it's recognizing it and all that.

I used 
    allow_soft_placement=True
but it just gave the model building to the GPU and the training to the CPU.

(The only edit I made was line 2. To see the original code, go to the link I referenced earlier. Also, I'm only going to include the training portion because I learned the hard way that people don't like unnecessary code.)

```
def train(args):
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'): 
        # Create the data_loader object, which loads up all of our batches, vocab dictionary, etc.
        # from utils.py (and creates them if they don't already exist).
        # These files go in the data directory.
        data_loader = TextLoader(args.data_dir, args.batch_size, args.seq_length)
        args.vocab_size = data_loader.vocab_size

        load_model = False
        if not os.path.exists(args.save_dir):
            print("Creating directory %s" % args.save_dir)
            os.mkdir(args.save_dir)
        elif (os.path.exists(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'))):
            # Trained model already exists
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(args.save_dir)
            if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
                with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'), 'rb') as f:
                    saved_args = pickle.load(f)
                    args.block_size = saved_args.block_size
                    args.num_blocks = saved_args.num_blocks
                    args.num_layers = saved_args.num_layers
                    args.model = saved_args.model
                    print("Found a previous checkpoint. Overwriting model description arguments to:")
                    print(" model: {}, block_size: {}, num_blocks: {}, num_layers: {}".format(
                        saved_args.model, saved_args.block_size, saved_args.num_blocks, saved_args.num_layers))
                    load_model = True

        # Save all arguments to config.pkl in the save directory -- NOT the data directory.
        with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'config.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(args, f)
        # Save a tuple of the characters list and the vocab dictionary to chars_vocab.pkl in
        # the save directory -- NOT the data directory.
        with open(os.path.join(args.save_dir, 'chars_vocab.pkl'), 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump((data_loader.chars, data_loader.vocab), f)

        # Create the model!
        print("Building the model")
        model = Model(args)
        print("Total trainable parameters: {:,d}".format(model.trainable_parameter_count()))

        # Make tensorflow less verbose; filter out info (1+) and warnings (2+) but not errors (3).
        os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

        config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
        #config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
            tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
            saver = tf.train.Saver(model.save_variables_list(), max_to_keep=3)
            if (load_model):
                print("Loading saved parameters")
                saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
            global_epoch_fraction = sess.run(model.global_epoch_fraction)
            global_seconds_elapsed = sess.run(model.global_seconds_elapsed)
            if load_model: print("Resuming from global epoch fraction {:.3f},"
                    " total trained time: {}, learning rate: {}".format(
                    global_epoch_fraction,
                    datetime.timedelta(seconds=float(global_seconds_elapsed)),
                    sess.run(model.lr)))
            if (args.set_learning_rate > 0):
                sess.run(tf.assign(model.lr, args.set_learning_rate))
                print("Reset learning rate to {}".format(args.set_learning_rate))
            data_loader.cue_batch_pointer_to_epoch_fraction(global_epoch_fraction)
            initial_batch_step = int((global_epoch_fraction
                    - int(global_epoch_fraction)) * data_loader.total_batch_count)
            epoch_range = (int(global_epoch_fraction),
                    args.num_epochs + int(global_epoch_fraction))
            writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(args.save_dir, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
            outputs = [model.cost, model.final_state, model.train_op, model.summary_op]
            global_step = epoch_range[0] * data_loader.total_batch_count + initial_batch_step
            avg_loss = 0
            avg_steps = 0
            try:
                for e in range(*epoch_range):
                    # e iterates through the training epochs.
                    # Reset the model state, so it does not carry over from the end of the previous epoch.
                    state = sess.run(model.zero_state)
                    batch_range = (initial_batch_step, data_loader.total_batch_count)
                    initial_batch_step = 0
                    for b in range(*batch_range):
                        global_step += 1
                        if global_step % args.decay_steps == 0:
                            # Set the model.lr element of the model to track
                            # the appropriately decayed learning rate.
                            current_learning_rate = sess.run(model.lr)
                            current_learning_rate *= args.decay_rate
                            sess.run(tf.assign(model.lr, current_learning_rate))
                            print("Decayed learning rate to {}".format(current_learning_rate))
                        start = time.time()
                        # Pull the next batch inputs (x) and targets (y) from the data loader.
                        x, y = data_loader.next_batch()

                        # feed is a dictionary of variable references and respective values for initialization.
                        # Initialize the model's input data and target data from the batch,
                        # and initialize the model state to the final state from the previous batch, so that
                        # model state is accumulated and carried over between batches.
                        feed = {model.input_data: x, model.targets: y}
                        model.add_state_to_feed_dict(feed, state)

                        # Run the session! Specifically, tell TensorFlow to compute the graph to calculate
                        # the values of cost, final state, and the training op.
                        # Cost is used to monitor progress.
                        # Final state is used to carry over the state into the next batch.
                        # Training op is not used, but we want it to be calculated, since that calculation
                        # is what updates parameter states (i.e. that is where the training happens).
                        train_loss, state, _, summary = sess.run(outputs, feed)
                        elapsed = time.time() - start
                        global_seconds_elapsed += elapsed
                        writer.add_summary(summary, e * batch_range[1] + b + 1)
                        if avg_steps < 100: avg_steps += 1
                        avg_loss = 1 / avg_steps * train_loss + (1 - 1 / avg_steps) * avg_loss
                        print("{:,d} / {:,d} (epoch {:.3f} / {}), loss {:.3f} (avg {:.3f}), {:.3f}s" \
                            .format(b, batch_range[1], e + b / batch_range[1], epoch_range[1],
                                train_loss, avg_loss, elapsed))
                        # Every save_every batches, save the model to disk.
                        # By default, only the five most recent checkpoint files are kept.
                        if (e * batch_range[1] + b + 1) % args.save_every == 0 \
                                or (e == epoch_range[1] - 1 and b == batch_range[1] - 1):
                            save_model(sess, saver, model, args.save_dir, global_step,
                                    data_loader.total_batch_count, global_seconds_elapsed)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                # Introduce a line break after ^C is displayed so save message
                # is on its own line.
                print()
            finally:
                writer.flush()
                global_step = e * data_loader.total_batch_count + b
                save_model(sess, saver, model, args.save_dir, global_step,
                        data_loader.total_batch_count, global_seconds_elapsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the model contains an operation for which GPU-support is not enabled, so letting `soft_placement` handles it is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

yes, something like this :

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 2, 'CPU': 2}, allow_soft_placement = True )
sess = tf.Session(config = config) 
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

here, GPU and CPU are the no. of processing unit devices available that you want to use